# Javascript help in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
 String sample=res[i][j][k].replaceAll(" ","_");

 out.print("<td align=center name="+sample+" onmouseover=tt(this.name)>");

  <script type="text/javascript">
        function tt(n){
                        var x=n;
            alert(x);
                    }
    </script>
```

The alert box shows undefined on mouseover. The value "sample" that i am passing is correct as i have already tested that.
Any suggestions?
Is there any other method by which i can pass the value "sample" to the javascript function on mouseover?

Comment: Use a tool like firebug to see what is exactly there on your page after execution of `out.print(...`. check if the name is acually "sample"

Comment: Does the JavaScript not do what you expect? Show us the HTML and the JavaScript (not the JSP!). Is the JSP failing to generate the JS/HTML you expect? Show us what it generates and explain how that differs from what you want.

Comment: You have some obvious errors, [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: TD elements don’t have a `name` attribute. Use an HTML5 custom data attribute instead. And learn to write/create _correct_ HTML code – attribute values should be encapsulated in `"` or `'`, especially if the contain anything else than just common letters/numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If `sample` is in fact set, you should be able to to:

```
<% String sample = res[i][j][k].replaceAll(" ", "_"); %>
<td align="center" name="<%= sample %>" onmouseover="tt(this.name)">

// rest here
```

Although, I would probably prefer to expose `sample` as a request attribute from your servlet instead:

```
request.setAttribute("sample", res[i][j][k].replaceAll(" ", "_");
```

and access it in the JSP instead.

However, none of this will help unless `sample` is actually set correctly. And it's not clear if your example is actually what you have tried, or just "pseudo" code.

**Edit** 
I was not considering if your javascript is actually correct. So check the actual generated HTML. Your error might be elsewhere.

Comment: grr... now you were a few seconds faster than me, point up for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String sample=res[i][j][k].replaceAll(" ","_");

out.print("<td align=center name='"+sample+"' onmouseover=tt(this.name)>");

<script type="text/javascript">
     function tt(n){
                    var x=n;
        alert(x);
                }
  </script>
```

Just change the name in the out.print so that its treated as a proper string. Should post this, or the above answer give by @NilsH should also work :)

Answer (score 0):

rather than using

`this.name`

try passing **this as argument** and in the calling method do something like this

```
this.getAttribute("name")
```